# laravel + AngularJs: cant execute SQL command

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel

I just bought a script (from codecanyon) that built by Laravel and AngularJS, now, When Im trying to Get "DB::raw" from SQL (To show a table in backend) it give me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pushes.title'
> in 'field list' (SQL: select pushes.title, pushes.created_at ....

I can understand the error, there is not "pushes.title" in sql table, It looks like all js objects does not translated to values, for example "pushes.title" should be "title" in database, and so on.

Here is the function that send the get command:

> public function getDataReport($filters=array(),$orders=array()){
>
> ```
>     $pushes = \Push::select(\DB::raw("        pushes.title,
>     pushes.created_at,
>                                                 pushes.id as pushes_id,
>                                                 pushes.message,
>                                                 pushes.notify_trigger,
>                                                 pushes_to_locations.id as pushes_to_locations_id,
>                                                 pushes_to_locations.location_id,
>                                                 pushes_to_locations.status,
>                                                 locations.lat,
>                                                 locations.address_formated,
>                                                 locations.lng,
>                                                 locations.radius"));
>     $pushes->join('pushes_to_locations','pushes.id','=','pushes_to_locations.pushes_id');
>     $pushes->join('locations','locations.id','=','pushes_to_locations.location_id');
>
>     if(!empty($filters['status'])){
>         $pushes->whereRaw("(status = ".$filters['status'].")");
>     }
>     if(!empty($filters['text'])){
>         $pushes->where("title",'like',"%".$filters['text']."%");
>         $pushes->orWhere("message",'like',"%".$filters['text']."%");
>     }
>
>     $noSort = true;
>     foreach($orders as $col => $orderValue) {
>         if(empty($orderValue)) { continue; };
>         $noSort = false;
>         $pushes->orderBy($col,$orderValue);
>     }
>     if(($noSort)){
>         //$orderColumns['order_date'] ='DESC';
>         $pushes->orderBy('pushes.created_at','desc');
>     }
>     //echo $apps->toSql();
>     return $pushes->paginate(20);
> } }
> ```

What am I missing here? should I need to Install something else?

Here is the backend instructions:

http://ec2-54-179-166-43.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/geofencing/public/backend-guide

(all the rest is fully working for me, So I assume that most of the installation is fine)

Thanks in advance!!

Eran.

Comment: The error message says that column `title` doesn't exist in the `pushes` table. What's the confusion?

Comment: It is exist, the error says that: "pushes.title" is not exist, and indeed its not..

Comment: Sorry, your comment makes no sense.

Comment: you can see that here its working fine: http://ec2-54-179-166-43.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/geofencing/public/push/get-data?filters%5Btext%5D=&orders%5Baddress_formated%5D=&orders%5Bcreated_at%5D=&orders%5Bmessage%5D=&orders%5Bnotify_trigger%5D=&orders%5Bpushes_to_locations_id%5D=&orders%5Bstatus%5D=&orders%5Btitle%5D=&page=1&page_size=10    user:admin Password:admin

Comment: Im just saying that it is exist, I have a table "pushes" with column "title", the thing is its not looking for "title" its looking for "pushes.title" from some reason, if I will change it from "pushes.title: to "title" the error will be gone (and it will fail on the next 'not translated' object), got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Hope you will be faster then me, The problem was only my database prefix, from some reason, this code ignore my db prefix, thats why it couldn't find it, I have added the prefix and everything is fine now.

Thank you anyway!